# orderBy not working with pagination and filters

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, pagination, angularjs-orderby

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="col-md-3" ng-click="sortDirection = !sortDirection">Created At</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr dir-paginate="food in foods | filter:foodFilter | itemsPerPage:pageSize | orderBy:'created_at_date'">
        <td class="col-md-"> {{food.created_at_date}} </td>
</tbody>
</table>

<dir-pagination-controls
    max-size= 7
    boundary-links="true">
</dir-pagination-controls>
```

This is only a snippet of my code but its too large to put up. Everything is working except only some of the created_at_date is in order. When I click on a different filter to add in or remove data depending on that filter, only some of it is entered into the correct place. My main question is: is there someway to sort all of the dates properly while still allowing the everything else function as well? All help is welcome, Thanks

```
 (function () {
"use strict";

App.controller('foodsController', ['$scope'],
    function($scope) {
        $scope.sortDirection  = true;
```

Comment: I noticed you're missing `</tr>` tag in `<tbody>`.

Comment: If the orderBy attribute isn't working, you could try adding that method on your controller and before handling food in the template, you could order the foods array before it's exposed to the template, ie `foods = sortBy('created_at_date', foods);` or `dir-paginate="food in sortBy('created_at_date', foods) | ..." `

Comment: @ShannonHochkins I tried your ` dir-paginate="food in sortBy('created_at_date', foods) | filter:foodFilter | itemsPerPage:pageSize">` but none of the array showed up. I dont quite understand what you mean add the orderBy method to the controller?

Comment: @user3328281 I've elaborated with an answer

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you can add the method to order the array before you loop over them.

Assuming your foods array has an array of objects, each with a key of created_at_date and a value:

```
App.controller('foodsController', function($scope) {

  $scope.foods = [{
    created_at_date: 6791234
  }, {
    created_at_date: 9837245
  }, {
    created_at_date: 1234755
  }];

  // create a method exposed to the scope for your template.

  $scope.orderBy = function(key, array) {
    // now you've received the array, you can sort it on the key in question.
    var sorted = array.sort(function(a, b) {
      return a[key] - b[key];
    });
    return sorted;
  }

});
```

Now on your template, you have a method available to sort your values for you:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="col-md-3" ng-click="sortDirection = !sortDirection">Created At</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr dir-paginate="food in orderBy('created_at_date', foods) | filter:foodFilter | itemsPerPage:pageSize">
            <td class="col-md-"> {{food.created_at_date}} </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The `orderBy` method which we've created on your controller returns an array, but it's just sorted by the key that's sent in as the first argument of the function. The second argument is the original array you're trying to sort.

At least this way you can check if you remove all your other filters to see if it's ordered correctly, if then after you add them back in it changes it's because those filters are also changing the order.